# Convert multiple DataTables to columns in a single datagridview

Tags: c#

I have three DataTables in C# called MIT, Oracle and Difference. Could you please let me know how to add these three tables to a gridview as seperate columns? I know how to bind a DataTable to a gridview as given below. But i need the same to be done for several DataTables.Please help

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = MIT;
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkxgP.png)'s an image of the GridView.

Comment: You need to merge these DataTables. But how are they related to each other, can you join them?

Comment: I need to compare part numbers in "MIT" and "Oracle" Data tables and add the differences to "Difference" data table. All the DataTables contain only one column called "part Number"

Comment: Can you show reduced sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should combine your tables into a `DataSet` and then use a common column (I presume there is one!) to create `DataRelations` between the tables. This will allow you to bind your `DataGridView` to the result of a query on the `DataSet`.

For more info: see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you add these three different tables in the GridView (adding columns of each DataTable). How would you populate the data in each row as all three might be different. So there must be some way to first join these tables into one based on any relationship then you can associate/bind the resultant DataTable to GridView:

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> result = 
              from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              join t1 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
              on t1.Field<int>("KeyId") equals
                  t2.Field<int>("KeyId")
              select new
              {
                   KeyId = t1.Field<int>("KeyId"),
                   Column1 = t1.Field<string>("Column1"),
                   Column2 = t2.Field<string>("Column2"), 
                   .
                   . 
              };

dataGridView1.DataSource = result.AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should merge your multiple datatables into one datatable and then give it as datasource to datagridview.below link will help for merging datatables to one.

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/bind-mult-table-gridview-asp4.aspx

**OR**

you should SELECT your data into a single table using the appropriate joins. DataGridViews display their data in a single-table format - there is no "multiple table" concept in a DataGridView.

`DataSet.Merge()` can help you to merge DataRows from separate objects into one.